# MVC EF How to assign values in configuration.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, configuration-files

I'm trying to assign one of my Tickets with a adminID by using either  `AdminID = 1`  and `dminID = administrator.Single(c => c.AdminID == 1 ).AdminID,`but neither of them seems to work. After executing `update-database` in the Package Manager Console it seems to have no effect:

[image]

Configration.cs

```
namespace RecreationServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext>
    {
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
    {

        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations"}

        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var depots = new List<Depot>
        {
            new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},


        };
        depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},

    };


        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstMidName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
        };
        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var administrator = new List<Administrator>
        {
            new Administrator { AdminRole = "Administrator LVL1", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator { AdminRole = "Administrator LVL2", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator { AdminRole = "Administrator LVL3", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() }

        };
        administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.UserID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();




        var tickets = new List<Ticket>
        {
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,

                Issue = ("Test Error 1"),
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,

                Issue = ("Test Error 2"),
                Priority = Priority.Med
            },
        };


        foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
        {
            var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                s =>
                    s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                    s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ticketInDataBase == null)
            {
                context.Tickets.Add(e);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Administrator.cs

```
public class Administrator
    {
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AdminRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }


    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

}
```

Ticket.cs

```
   public class Ticket
    {
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
        public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("TicketID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

IssueContext.cs

```
public class IssueContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Administrators).WithMany(i => i.Tickets)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("TicketID")
                    .MapRightKey("AdministratorID")
                    .ToTable("AdministratorsTickets"));


            modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
                       .HasKey(e => e.UserID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.User)
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.Administrator);


        }
    }
```

This mapping tool is causing this error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Administrator_User_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Administrator_User_Target' in relationship 'Administrator_User'.
>   Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the
>   upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
           .HasKey(e => e.UserID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.User)
    .WithRequired(ad => ad.Administrator);
```

This is the working one

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
                   .HasKey(e => e.UserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Administrator) 
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.User);
```

Comment: What does your ticket class look like?

Comment: OK, your admin model is off. You have that as 1:1 with user and have properly defined it's key (UserId) as a FK into User. So get rid of AdminId - it serves no purpose since UserId is both the PK of Admin and FK into User. Don't think you need TicketId either since you are 1:* with the collection. Now you need to correct the other models with AdminId to use UserId.

Comment: See this link. Change Student to User and StudentAddress to Administrator. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @ZachM. Updated the ticket class

Comment: @SteveGreene My classes look the same as the link you provide. I edited my question to show the IssueContext as well.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - in the question you imply that you're updating the ticket table during migration to set the admin id, and give a fragment of code of how you get this value.  Yet in the `Seed` method, no where does your code set or update this value.  Can you please clarify

Comment: @BrendanGreen I was following Steve Greene's instructions and he advice me not to use adminID. I edited the question so its not there anymore.

Comment: @SteveGreene I stuffed up my relation between User and Admin. What happens if i want my user to not be required to be an admin. Some users are admins and some aren't.

Comment: Keep your ticket class like it was in the original answer. Ticket.AdminId can be set independently of Ticket.UserId. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762425/mvc-conflicting-changes-detected-mvc-ef/35779572#35779572